# How to install TDengine database on Mac OS

Tags: tdengine

I follow the step from this link https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine to install TDengine on my mac (Big Sur 11.1). After I run `make install` command, I got this error message at the end:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:75 (file):
file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

/Users/Documents/taos/TDengine/debug/install_manifest.txt


make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'sudo make install' to get permission granted.